# Installing SQL server 2005 if SQL Server 2008 is installed

Tags: setup-project, setup-deployment, bootstrapper

My application runs on SQL Server 2005.  I have added bootstraper to install SQL Server Express 2005.  It ensures to install SQL Server Express 2005 at installation time.

My question is if my user has already got SQL Server 2008?  Will the bootstraper still work the same way?  Will it be able to install SQL Server 2005 as 2008 is advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The predefined SQL Server 2005 prerequisite in Visual Studio uses a custom EXE to determine if it needs to be installed or not. So you cannot see the detection criteria.

You can try testing the scenario you mentioned on a clean machine and see what happens. This is the only way you can determine if it will be installed or not.